# iOS strings file collision - Same string in source langage, different in target

Tags: ios, cocoa, localization, nslocalizedstring

So, I'm localizing an app from japanese to english.

In japanese, there is no distinction between (say) "Mr." and "Ms."(/"Mrs."), so I need to do something like this:

```
/* Salutation format for user (male) */
"%@様" = "Mr. %@";

/* Salutation format for user (female) */
"%@様" = "Ms. %@";
```

As you can see, the Japanese localization uses the same string in both cases. I was under the impression that, when the strings file contains more than one entry with the same 'source' (i.e., left side) string, the 'comment' was used to determine which one was employed. **It turns out I was wrong, and the comment parameter is just an aid for human translators, totally ignored by `NSLocalizedString()`**.

So if I run the app, both of the code paths below produce the same string, regardless of the user's gender:

```
NSString* userName;
BOOL userIsMale;

/* userName and userIsMale are set... */

NSString* format;

if(userIsMale){
    // MALE
    format = NSLocalizedString(@"%@様", 
                               @"Salutation format for user (male)");
}
else{
    // FEMALE
    format = NSLocalizedString(@"%@様", 
                               @"Salutation format for user (female)");
}

NSString* salutation = [NSString stringWithFormat:format, userName];
```

So, how should I deal with a case like this?

Comment: i don't no how u get new idea, this seems silly but u could give it a try by giving a space for "@%@様 "  i added a space and other for without space "@%@様". this is just a try, don't consider it as solution

Comment: and also check the format of localised string "%@様" = "Mr. %@"; it begines with "key" = "value"; format u added "@" at the beginning of each pairs

Comment: Yes, the syntax for my Localizable.strings example is wrong, I'll fix it. thank you.

Comment: and what about ur issue with same key's

Comment: The issue is, I hoped I could get different values with the same key, depending on the "comment" part. I was wrong...

Comment: Mmh, no. I need to come up with something... The "add a space" solution you suggested is not very elegant, but it may be the only one. I'm asking just in case, and to contribute to the discussion.

Comment: try it may work for ur case ... :)

Comment: Thats not the point. I'm sure there's something the english language does not distinguish that other languages do (e.g., noun gender). So if (say) I localise from english to french, I'll be on the same situation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, actually “left side” of the `NSLocalizedString` is a key. So you could do something like:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"SalutForUserMale", @"Salutation format for user (male)");
NSLocalizedString(@"SalutForUserFemale", @"Salutation format for user (female)");
```

Then in your base `*.strings` file (Japanese I presume) you would have:

```
"SalutForUserMale" = "%@様";
"SalutForUserFemale" = "%@様";
```

And in your English `*.strings` file you would have:

```
"SalutForUserMale" = "Mr. %@";
"SalutForUserFemale" = "Ms. %@";
```

Comment: Thank you, you are absolutely right. The only caveat is that you lose the "use key string as default when entry is not found" fallback functionality  (if there's a missing entry - something very likely if you make/extend the string files manually) and the user may end up facing a cryptic string. But that's a risk worth taking/testing.

Answer (score 2):

The Localizable.strings files are nothing more than key value lists. You are using the Japanese phrases as keys which is unusual but I guess it works. I assume this is because the original app was developed in Japanese(?). I usually use English phrases keys, but whatever.

The point is that **if you want two different phrases in even just one translation you have to have two different keys in all your translations**. If there is something in your base language that is not distinguished but in the translations it is, then you can just "split" an existing key in two new ones. Just change it slightly or add a number, see below:

```
/* english .strings file */
"hello_world_key" = "Hello World";
"Yes1" = "Yes"; // same in english but different values in german
"Yes2" = "Yes";

/* german .strings file */
"hello_world_key" = "Hallo Welt";
"Yes1" = "Ja";
"Yes2" = "Jawohl";
```